# Incrementing and resetting a PHP session variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to keep score on a quiz I'm making using PHP session variables. I want the score to increment for a right answer, and to reset to 0 if you choose to skip a question. Skipping correctly resets it to 0, but score won't increment past 1 for successive correct answers. Here's the session_start() portion:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) 
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;

if (!isset($_SESSION['skipped'])) 
    $_SESSION['skipped'] = FALSE;

if($_SESSION['skipped'] == TRUE){
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['skipped'] = !$_SESSION['skipped'];
}
?>
```

The logic for adding to the score:

```
<script>
        var key = <?php echo json_encode($rand_key) ?>;

        function my_submit(curr) {
            var info = curr.guess.value;

            if (key.toLowerCase()==info.toLowerCase()){
                <?php
                    $x = $_SESSION['score'] + 1;
                    $_SESSION['score'] = $x;
                ?>

                var up_score = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
                alert('Correct! Score: ' + up_score);
                return true;
            }

                alert('Incorrect!');
                return false;

        }
    </script>
```

And for resetting the score:

```
<script>
        var answer = <?php echo json_encode($rand_key) ?>;

        function skipped(){
            <?php
                    $q = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['skipped'] = $q;
                ?>
            alert('Correct answer: ' + answer + '. Your score has been reset for skipping.');
            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

This site has been unbelievably helpful; thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: And your issue is...?

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like this. PHP runs server-side, so it has already executed before the browser starts running your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write PHP in the middle of some JavaScript functions as if you expect it to be executed by the JavaScript itself.

If you remove the HTML/JS output, you can see what actually happens on the server as soon as you load the page (I assume your code snippets are in order):

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) 
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;

if (!isset($_SESSION['skipped'])) 
    $_SESSION['skipped'] = FALSE;

if($_SESSION['skipped'] == TRUE){
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['skipped'] = !$_SESSION['skipped'];
}
$x = $_SESSION['score'] + 1;
$_SESSION['score'] = $x;

$q = TRUE;
$_SESSION['skipped'] = $q;
```

On the first page load with an empty session, this will set `$_SESSION['score']` to `0` (because it's not set yet), then increment it to `1`, then set `$_SESSION['skipped']` to `true`.

On subsequent page loads, it will set `$_SESSION['score']` to `0` (because *skipped* is set), then increment it again to `1` and finally setting `skipped` to `true` again (you see: nothing changed)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. I'll find another way.